# ¿Problema con la compilación para ios de nativescript por que pesa mas build de ios que el de androd?

Tags: ios, nativescript

En android build pesa 5 megas y en ios build pesa 300mb hay forma de solucionar esto ?

Comment: No compila en iOS por el peso?

Comment: Si compila, pero el peso en ios es de 200 megas mientras que el de android es de 4 megas, ese el problema

Comment: Cuando haces el Archive en Xcode te sale los 200MB?

Comment: Si, cuando compilo el código que proporciona nativescript e instalo la app pesa 200 mb  mientras que el codigo que proporiciona nativescript para android la app pesa 4 megas, es normal ?

Comment: Estos comando te pueden servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027476/nativescript-build-ios-big-size-ipa. Aunque parece que ya depende de Nativescript.